# How to fix TypeError: "NoneType" is not iterable?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a program that is meant to go through all four digit numbers and order their digits in ascending order to create another number, and then all of them in descending order. Substracting these should give another `4` digit number. Repeating this process a few times eventually gives a resulting number of `6174`. I want my program to test this for all `4` digit numbers.

I've tried `[str(i) for i in bigdigits]` and other lines in the Python Console and it worked out fine. But I can't get it to work in the actual program.

I tried debugging this to no result. As well as printing out all partial results for variables. The result of printing all of the lists is None.

```
counter = 1000
while counter != 10000:
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(counter)]
    bigdigits = digits.sort(reverse = True)
    smalldigits = digits.sort()

    strbigdigs = [str(i) for i in bigdigits]
    bignum = int("".join(strbigdigs))

    strsmalldigs = [str(j) for j in smalldigits]
    smallnum = int("".join(smalldigits))

    partialanswer = bignum - smallnum
    print(partialanswer)
```

For example, if counter were `2019`, digits should be `[2, 0, 1, 9]` and bigdigits would be `[9, 2, 1, 0]`. Then strbigdigs would be `['9', '2', '1', '0']`. Finally, bignum would be `9210`.

Comment: There are many existing questions here about the same issue. You can find them by searching on the error message. Surely one of those can give you an idea of how to solve this yourself.

Comment: Hello Ken. Thank you for your comment. While I have found similar questions, many of the problems I  them were caused by certain operations just like mine, causing the list to hold the value of None. Unfortunately, the actual command that was causing that was not the same as what I have in any of those cases. I probably am missing something I haven't noticed. I am very inexperienced.

Comment: Always post the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same exact code to explain the problem and how to fix it. If you're having trouble adding the integer variables `x` and `y`, an answer that explains how to add the integer variables `a` and `b` would still give you an answer. You have a variable that is resolving to `NoneType`, and you're trying to iterate using that variable. The issue is clear, and it's also clear where the iteration is happening. So you need to figure out why you're getting `NoneType` in that area of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your code:

- `list.sort` will sort the list inplace and will return `None` (use `sorted` instead).
- `smallnum = int("".join(smalldigits))` should be `smallnum = int("".join(strsmalldigs))`.
- at the end of your loop, you should give `counter` the value of `partialanswer`.
- since you know it will always stop at `6174`, put that in your `while` loop test.

```
counter = 2019

while counter != 6174:
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(counter)]
    bigdigits = sorted(digits, reverse = True)
    smalldigits = sorted(digits)

    strbigdigs = [str(i) for i in bigdigits]
    bignum = int("".join(strbigdigs))

    strsmalldigs = [str(j) for j in smalldigits]
    smallnum = int("".join(strsmalldigs))

    partialanswer = bignum - smallnum
    print(partialanswer)
    counter = partialanswer
```

Output:

```
9081
9621
8352
6174
```